# (Styling): How to join multiple selectors and give them the same attributes inside of sx

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add them both in one line (join the selectors together, but it did not work:
I tried `.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator .MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicatorOpen`, tried nesting objects, and some other things, but none of them worked.

```
  <Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  options={[1, 2, 3]}
  sx={{
    width: 1,
    '.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator': {
      bgcolor: 'transparent',
      mr: 2,
    },
    '.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicatorOpen': {
      bgcolor: 'transparent',
      mr: 2,
    },
  }}
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

How can I join multiple selectors and give them the same attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the styles like this

```
<Autocomplete 
        disablePortal
        options={[1, 2, 3]}
        sx={{
          width: 1,
          '& .MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator, &.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicatorOpen': {
            bgcolor: 'transparent',
            mr: 2,
          }
        }}
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends of what exactly you want to achieve, but you definitely need to use the `&` sign:

```
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  options={[1, 2, 3]}
  sx={{
    width: 1,
    '& .MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator': {
      bgcolor: 'transparent',
      mr: 2,
    },
    '& .MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicatorOpen': {
      bgcolor: 'transparent',
      mr: 2,
    },
  }}
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

Or like this, applying the styles no matter of `Autocomplete` open state:

```
<Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      options={[1, 2, 3]}
      sx={{
        width: 1,
        '& .MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator': {
          bgcolor: 'transparent',
          mr: 2,
        }
      }}
      renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
```

**Edit**
This is absolutely redundant, because the `.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator` selector is one level above and includes completely the `.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicatorOpen` selector in itself, in the code there is **nothing that is specific for the open state** that is different from the closed state, so there is no reason for this additional selector...